# Page view as a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm interested if it is possible and if possible how to embed some kind of a page view control into a small view on a screen and react on taps on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a container view. Container views allow for page views and scroll views alike to be nested like a normal UIView which you can place within other views. As far as tapping to switch pages, use a touchesBegan function to call the next page.